# IE8 fires unintentional action (javascript) (textbox action when changed doesn't work)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, textbox, action, onchange

I dispair slowly and my last nerves get lost.
I have an element in a table. If I click on this element I get a textbox and if I press enter, the value from the textbox will be processed by a php-script. So far it works perfekt, but...
Now I need, that if I click outside the box, better say on an other element, the same popup window should appear (do you need to change blabla) as on the action when I press the enter-button.
I tried with focusout, blur, onchange, etc, but the IE fires the popup immediatelly, so I just have no chance to type anything in the textbox!
Here my code which works good only with enter-action (enter button):

```
function modify(value, item_ID, attr_NAME, obj_name){
    $('.ajax').html($('.ajax_input').val());
    $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
    $(value).addClass('ajax');
    $(value).html(
             '<input id="editbox" size="' + $(value).text().length
                     + '" type="text" value="' + $(value).text()
                     + '" onkeydown="confirmAction(this.value, ' + item_id
                     + ", '" + attr_name + "'" + ", '" + obj_name + "'" + ')">');
    $('#editbox').focus();
}
```

**Got it to work:**

```
$('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
    $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
    $(value).addClass('ajax');
    $(value).html(
            '<input id="editbox"' + ' type="text" value="' + $(value).text() + '"/>');
    $('#editbox').focus();

    $('#editbox').keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            $(document).attr('helpAttr', false);
            confirmAction(this.value, item_id, attr_name, obj_name);
        }
    });
    $('#editbox').blur(
            function() {
                if ($(document).attr('helpAttr')
                        || ($(document).attr('helpAttr') == undefined)) {
                    confirmAction(this.value, item_id, attr_name, obj_name);
                } else {
                    $(document).attr('helpAttr', true);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Do you want the event to fire ONLY when you press ENTER so you can enter a value? Because now it fires on any key.

Comment: I need an event on Enter and if I click on other elements or simply outside

Comment: I understand, but you want to be able to enter a value into the textbox, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This handles the enter key:

```
$('#editbox').keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    confirmAction(...);
 }
}
```

This handles the click outside:

```
$('#editbox').blur(function() {
    confirmAction(...);
}
```

Comment: works great, but there is a problem. they are fired together. Have I did a mistake somewhere?

Comment: in this case add `event.preventDefault()` and maybe `event.stopPropagation()` before `confirmAction(...);` in the keydown handler. The first one should be enough.

Comment: When does blur fire? When you hit ENTER? And how does your code look now. Can you provide a Fiddle?

Comment: yes, if I hit enter blur() event fires. I just added alert() and got object expected error in IE8

Comment: I'll writting tomorrow, but thank you very much for your great help